# Convergence Events with States

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

Ignatz repeatedly rolls a fair $6$-sided die. What is the probability that he rolls his first $5$ before he rolls his second (not necessarily distinct) even number?

I don't know what to do about the *second even number.

Can someone give me a hint, and or a solution?

Comment: Hint:  Do it with states.  Let $S(0)$ be the starting state, $S(1)$ be the state in which one even number has been tossed, and we have a Win and a Loss state.  Starting in $S(0)$ you move to $S(1)$ with probability $\frac 36$, to Win with probability $\frac 16$ and back to $S(0)$ with probability $\frac  26$.  Keep going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We say Ignatz wins if he rolls two even numbers before a $5$. What is the probability he wins in turn $n+2$? It is equal to the probability he rolls an even number in turn $n+2$ and exactly one even number before turn $n+2$. There are $2^{n}$ ways to through the odd numbers , $n+1$ ways to select the turn in which the first even number is thrown and $3$ options for the first even number

So the probability he wins in turn $n+2$ is $(n+1)\frac{1}{2}\frac{2^{n}}{6^{n}}\frac{3}{6}=(n+1)\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{3}^{n})$

So we want $\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)(\frac{1}{3})^n=\frac{1}{4}(\sum_{n=0}^n\frac{1}{3}^n)^2=\frac{1}{4}(\frac{1}{1-1/3})^2=\frac{1}{4}\frac{9}{4}=\frac{9}{16}$

So the probability a $5$ is thrown before two fives is $\frac{7}{16}=0.4375$

This coincides with what I got doing a simulation with $100,000,000$ tries, I got $0.43747$

Answer (score 3):

Two methods:

Method I.  Just to give a different approach, I'll write out the calculation via states.

Our states:  $S(0)$ is the starting state, no even numbers and no fives have been thrown.  $S(1)$ is the state after one exactly one even number (but no fives) have been thrown.  And we have Win and Loss states (where a Win here means a five is thrown before the second even number). Similarly let $p(0)$ be the probability of winning from $S(0)$ and $p(1)$ be the probability of winning from $S(1)$

Start at $S(0)$ and roll the die.  If you get a $1$ or a $3$ you stay in $S(0)$ (probability $\frac 26$).  If you get a $2,4,6$ you move to $S(1)$ (probability $\frac 36$ and if you throw a $5$ you move to Win (probability $\frac 16$).  Hence $$p(0)=\frac 36 p(1)\;+\;\frac 16\,1\;+\;\frac 26 p(0)\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;4p(0)=3p(1)+1$$

Similarly, starting from $S(1)$ you Win with probablity $\frac 16$, Lose with probaiblity $\frac 36$ and stay in $S(1)$ with probability $\frac 26$.  Hence $$p(1)=\frac 26 p(1)\;+\;\frac 36\,0\;+\;\frac16\,1\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;p(1)=\frac 14$$.  Combining the two we see that $p(0)=\frac {7}{16}$

Method II. as an easier method:  As throwing a $1$ or a $3$ changes nothing, let's ignore those cases and just imagine a $4$ sided die with sides $E,E,E,5$.  Then the only ways to win are to throw a $5$ on the first throw (probability $\frac 14$) or to throw $E,5$ in two throws (probability $\frac 34\frac 14=\frac {3}{16}$).  Hence the answer is $$\frac 14\;+\;\frac {3}{16}=\frac {7}{16}$$